# Using Oracle build-in UPPER function in WHERE lead to bad performance of SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance, sqlperformance, sql-tuning

Our Oracle database application contains a Table called `PERSON`
This Table contains a column called `PERSON_NAME`
Also we have an `INDEX` on this column to speed up `SELECT` using this column

So when we use following SQL statement performance is fine

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSON
WHERE 1=1
AND PERSON_NAME = '  Yajli  '
;
```

But in ***some*** business cases
*We need to make search by `PERSON_NAME` is NOT case sensitive*

So We try following SQL statement

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSON
WHERE 1=1
AND UPPER(PERSON_NAME) = UPPER('  YajLi  ')
;
```

But it lead us to a BAD performance and SELECT query in this case take a lot of time

Any Help How to enhance performance of `SELECT` on both cases together
*   search by `PERSON_NAME` is NOT case sensitive
*   search by `PERSON_NAME` is case sensitive

Comment: You could create an index on `upper(person_name)`

Comment: The second query is slow because it cannot use the existing index. Crete a function-based index on `UPPER(PERSON_NAME)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would have bad relative performance because the original query uses an index on `PERSON_NAME`.  However, when you apply a function, Oracle no longer uses the index.

If this is something that you need to do frequently (as you suggest), then you can create an index on the function:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_person_upper_personname ON PERSON(UPPER(PERSONNAME));
```

Then Oracle will use this index when you use the function `UPPER(PERSON)` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: So you mean we have to add 2 index on the same column - one normal `person_name` and one for upper `upper(person_name)` .. right?

Comment: @Yajli Maclo: Yes, you need both indexes to support both types of queries.

Comment: One functional index is sufficient to improve performance .i.e[PERSON(UPPER(PERSONNAME));.]